# Need help deserializing json string with C# javascriptserializer

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

I'm trying to deserialize the following json string in C# but it's not working correctly.

The following code returns a count of 0. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Addresses addresses = ser.Deserialize<Addresses>(json);
```

My JSON is:

```
{
  "addresses":[
{
  "first_name":"Sarah",
  "last_name":"Halawani",
  "line1":"1653 OCEAN PKWY",
  "company":"",
  "city":"BROOKLYN",
  "state":"NY",
  "subscriber_id":null,
  "country_name":"United States",
  "country_abbreviation":"USA",
  "latitude":"40.6085",
  "longitude":"-73.9675",
  "verified":true
},
{
  "first_name":"Jean",
  "last_name":"Mizrahi",
  "line1":"1733 OCEAN PKWY",
  "company":"",
  "city":"BROOKLYN",
  "state":"NY",
  "subscriber_id":null,
  "country_name":"United States",
  "country_abbreviation":"USA",
  "latitude":"40.6065",
  "longitude":"-73.9671",
  "verified":true
}
  ]
}
```

And my classes are:

```
public class Addresses
{
    public List<Address> address { get; set; }
    public Addresses() { address = new List<Address>(); }
}

public class Address
{
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string line1 { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: does you json variable contains data? you haven't included that part of the code

Comment: This was fixed by correcting a spellling mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled the property `address`.  It should be `addresses` to match the JSON property name:

```
public class Addresses
{
    public List<Address> addresses { get; set; }
    public Addresses() { addresses = new List<Address>(); }
}
```

To avoid errors like this, consider using a code-generation tool such as http://json2csharp.com/ or [Paste JSON as Classes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/12/18/paste-json-as-classes-in-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-rc/) in Visual Studio, and then manually removing unwanted properties.

Comment: Thanks dbc! That did it.